# InvalidDatasourceError: Datasource URL must use prisma:// protocol

Tags: next.js, graphql, prisma

I develop an Nextjs app.
The app is working as espected locally, both in development and production mode, using data in cloud.
The build on vercel works, the app works, but if I try to use my database I get this error on logs:

> InvalidDatasourceError: Datasource URL must use prisma:// protocol
> when --accelerate or --data-proxy are used

and

> api/graphql: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a
> status of 405

on browser console.

/graphql/builder.ts:

```
import SchemaBuilder from '@pothos/core';
import PrismaPlugin from '@pothos/plugin-prisma';
import RelayPlugin from '@pothos/plugin-relay';
import type PrismaTypes from '@pothos/plugin-prisma/generated';
import prisma from '../lib/prisma';

export const builder = new SchemaBuilder<{
  PrismaTypes: PrismaTypes;
}>({
  plugins: [PrismaPlugin, RelayPlugin],
  relayOptions: {},
  prisma: {
    client: prisma,
  },
});

builder.queryType({});
builder.mutationType({});
```

/lib/apollo.ts:

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';

export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
  uri: '/api/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

/lib/prisma.ts:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

let prisma: PrismaClient;

declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient;
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  prisma = new PrismaClient();
} else {
  if (!global.prisma) {
    global.prisma = new PrismaClient();
  }
  prisma = global.prisma;
}

export default prisma;
```

/api/graphql.ts:

```
import { schema } from '../../graphql/schema';
import { createYoga } from 'graphql-yoga';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default createYoga<{
  req: NextApiRequest;
  res: NextApiResponse;
}>({
  schema,
  graphqlEndpoint: process.env.GRAPHQL_API,
});

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
```

/prisma/schema.prisma:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

generator pothos {
  provider = "prisma-pothos-types"
}

datasource db {
  provider     = "mysql"
  url          = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}
```

My.env:

```
DATABASE_URL_development=mysql://<user>:<pass>@<host>/<myDB>?sslaccept=strict
```

package.json:

```
...
next@13.4.10
graphql@16.7.1
graphql-yoga@4.0.3
@apollo/client@3.7.17
@apollo/server@4.7.5
@prisma/client@5.0.0
prisma@5.0.0
...
```

And production build script:

```
    "vercel-build": "npx prisma generate --data-proxy && next build",
```

Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: As the error message suggests you would need to use the database connection string that starts with `prisma://`, you seem to be using the connection string starting with mysql. You should be able to get the prisma connection string from Accelarate UI

Comment: DATABASE_URL string to connect to Prisma was generated by planetscale with 'mysql:...'
I tried however to replace mysql with prisma, but ... same error message.
I saw that planetscale changed the host from us-east.connect.psdb.cloud to aws.connect.psdb.cloud.
I don't know if this has to do with the regions where Data Proxy infrastructure is currently available.

Comment: You don't need to replace `mysql://` with `prisma://`.Have you signed up for accelerate from this URL?
https://cloudprojects.prisma.io/login
If not, you would need to sign up and create a new project. The project will ask you to submit your database URL, you would need to provide the one starting with `mysql://`. After which you would get a new connection string that would start with `prisma://` that you need to use.

Answer (score 2):

you need to link the new connection string of the plantscale as you mentioned above and link it with Data proxy in Prisma, then when you are trying to generate the data you would use the mysql:// and the usage you will need to have the prisma/client/edge to use

and also you need the edit the connection string back to prisma://

Update

Prisma has migrated DataProxy to Accelerate which is similar to DataProxy

Comment: After I moved my repository to github, I applyed first data proxy (@KroKing) and then accelerate procedure (@Nurul), and both worked.

Comment: Yeah Prisma Have migrated to Accelerate, it same as data proxy